# How would you implement useCallback using useState from scratch?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is how I have implemented it. Does this look ok?

```
function useCallback(fn, deps) {
    const [state, setState] = useState({ fn });

    useEffect(() => {
        setState({ fn });
    }, deps);

    return state.fn;
}
```

Comment: What are the constraints? You can just return a function with `useMemo` :\

Comment: There are no constraints as such and this is just for learning sake. If I were to implement it using useState, how would I do it?

Comment: For learning purposes, this solution is good enough, although I would add more functionalities to `useCallback` like passing a comparison function (to not use shallow comparison only)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice try but not perfect. Your implementation calls `setState()` which triggers another round of re-render of component, that doesn’t match up to the behavior of the real `useCallback()` hook.

OK challenge accepted.

Actually `useState()` isn’t a good building block for implementing `useCallback()`, `useRef()` is better. But to meet your requirement, lemme first write `useRef()` with `useState()`.

```js
function useRef(value) {
  const [ref] = useState({ current: value })
  ref.current = value
  return ref
}
```

Easy piecy. We don’t need `useEffect()`. All we want is just a function to compare the deps between re-render and see if they change.

```js
function depsChanged(deps1, deps2) {
  if (deps1 === undefined || deps2 === undefined) return true
  if (deps1.length !== deps2.length) return true
  for (let i in deps1) {
    if (!Object.is(deps1[i], deps2[i])) return true
  }
  return false
}
```

Now we can implement `useCallback()`

```js
function useCallback(fn, deps) {
  const slots = useRef([fn, deps]).current
  if (depsChanged(slots[1], deps)) {
    slots[0] = fn
  }
  slots[1] = deps
  return slots[0]
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks! :)

Comment: I’ve written a lib for learning purpose before. https://github.com/hackape/fn-with-hooks It covers all react hooks but implemented from ground up. For your reference.

Comment: Will surely have a look. Thanks for sharing!